# I need to add a extra field in product rest api response - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, rest-api, slider

I want to add a field "slider" in /rest/V1/products/:sku

I created a custom module and in my di.xml i have added the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"> 
   <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product" type="mymod\Catalog\Model\Product" />
    <preference for="mymod\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface" type="mymod\Catalog\Model\Product" />
    <preference for="mymod\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" />
    <preference for="mymod\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface" />   
</config>
```

And I have added a method to Api/Data/ProductInterface

```
const slider = 'slider';

    public function getSlider();


    public function setSlider($slider);
```

I have implemented the two methods in

```
<?php 

namespace mymod\Catalog\Model;

class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product implements \Augmentes\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSlider()
    {
        return "test";
    }

    /**
     * Set slider value
     *
     * @param string $slider
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setSlider($slider)
    {
        return $this->setData('slider', "");
    } }
```

I also extended the ProductRepositoryInterface
changed the routes in webapi.xml

Still the field not coming in response. Anyone please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: any clue how to solve this ? I've got the same problem

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, Magento web API uses something like Extractor. Which converts data from object to array with usage of Interface as a template. So it's not enough to just add methods to class and interface, data with the same key should be in `_data` property.
Better to use [Extension Attributes](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html) technology. Then your field gonna be in `extension_attributes` field of product. It's safer and easier way.

Answer (score 0):

methods to test your code.

first check which api is getting called, your or default magento by putting some die in middle of code.

if it is coming from default then check your di.xml

if it is from your code make sure you deleted all cache and run setup-upgrade and static-content:deploy as well.